# How to use react-spreadsheet with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, validation, spreadsheet, react-hook-form

I want to build a form using react-spreadsheet and react-hook-form.
Not sure how to define the form schema in `Spreadsheet` component using react-hook-form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react hook form is just a wrapper instead of `const [value, setValue] = useState()` and some other helpers, it do nothing with your component, so the answer - the same as you build form with any other input, look at the Controller. The code sample for you for single field in a form:

```
<Controller
    name="description"
    control={control}
    render={({ field: { ref, ...restFields }, fieldState }) => {
      const element = <InputTextarea ref={ref} placeholder="Enter description" {...restField} />;
      if (excludeLabel) {
        return element;
      }

      return (
        <LabelWrapper label="Description" className="col-8" error={fieldState.error}>
          {element}
        </LabelWrapper>
      );
    }}
  />
```

`value`, `onChange` and `onBlur` - are inside `restFields` spread